# Sorting the index of this dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, training-data

I am trying to sort this dataset out currently:

```
     A  
1    x
101  y
104  a
11   b
111  z
119  c
13   d
131  w
```

I have applied the `sort_index()` function to my data frame, called `X_train` as such:

```
X_train.sort_index()
```

However, I would like my indices to be sorted like this:

```
     A  
1    x
11   b
13   d
101  y
104  a
111  z
119  c
131  w
```

Is this possible with any function in pandas, or any Pythonic library?

Comment: Looks like pandas `sort_index()` requires `inplace=True`, so maybe try `X_train.sort_index(inplace=True)`.

Comment: How does what you're doing now not work? (eg: if your index is numeric it should sort as you want - if it's text, then it won't...)

Comment: You are already doing it.

Comment: @PeptideWitch I just tried using that, and I got this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort_index'`

Comment: That means your `X_train` isn't defined properly, so you need to double check if your data frame is being defined as X_train. Feel free to post more of your code if you get stuck.

Comment: @PeptideWitch Ah, ok! I see that now. I'm looking into ways to hopefully convert to int now...

Comment: `df.index = df.index.astype(int); df = df.sort_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to sort your DataFrame:

- first on the **length** of the key (as a string),
- then on its **value**.

To do it you can use the following code:

```
df['ind'] = df.index.astype('str')
df['len'] = df.ind.str.len()
df = df.sort_values(['len', 'ind']).drop(columns=['len', 'ind'])
```

Another, more concise solution is:

```
df.iloc[np.argsort(df.index.map(lambda it: (len(str(it)), it)))]
```

The idea is:

- Compute a tuple "length, value" for each index value (the lambda function).
- Perform *argsort* - you get positions of rows sorted by these tuples.
- Retrieve elements from these positions.

Answer (score 0):

Either type:

```
X_train = X_train.sort_index()
```

or:

```
X_train.sort_index(inplace=True)
```